# AngularJS - show and hide arrow icon with glyphicon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a problem with the code, all I need is to hide the "NotesText" the arrow is pointing up, and after showing the "NotesText" arrow must be pointing down. I can not find the way to make this happen, please, I need help.

Basically, I need is to change the direction of the arrow agree if I need to show or hide

This is what I have .

**This is HTML:**

```
<div id="notes-controller" class="collapse in" ng-controller="NotesController">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="translatable" data-i18n="Notes">Notes</legend>
        <form novalidate class="simple-form">
            <div class="container col-md-12" ng-show="$ctrl.param.note.visible">
                <textarea class="col-md-12" ng-readonly="$ctrl.param.note.readonly" type="text" id="Notes" ng-model="$ctrl.notes.note" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<span type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#notes-controller"></span>
```

**This is Controller**

```
angular.
    module('notesText').
    component('notesText', {
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/test/notes-text/notes-text.template.html',
        bindings: {
            notes: '=',
            param: '='
        }
    }).controller('NotesController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.master = {};

        $scope.update = function (user) {
            $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
        };

        $scope.reset = function () {
            $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
        };

        $scope.reset();
    }]);
```

**This is how it looks:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEYm1.png)

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: cud u specify what is the output you expect?

Comment: @Iceman Alvaro expects something like this, http://i.stack.imgur.com/tEYm1.png

Comment: @DavidR coz he said "arrow shud be pointing down" or something and the upper arrow shud be hidden... I didnt quite understand.

Comment: @Iceman Basically what I need is, after clicking on the "arrow" it has to be pointing down hiding the content.   i.stack.imgur.com/tEYm1.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A very Minimalistic Soln:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" ng-app="">
  <textarea id="myTextArea" ng-hide="isHidden">MY TEXT</textarea>
  <br>

  <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="isHidden ? 'glyphicon-chevron-down' : 'glyphicon-chevron-up'" ng-click="isHidden = !isHidden;">
  </span>


</div>
```

**A more verbose Soln:**

Have a look at the working example below:

Simply using `ng-class` to attach  `glyphicon-chevron-up` or `glyphicon-chevron-down` based on expression returned by a function that checks if the `textarea` is visible.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.isShown = function() {
      return $('#myTextArea').is(':visible');
    }
    $scope.hideIt = function() {
      $('#myTextArea').toggle();
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <textarea id="myTextArea">MY TEXT</textarea>
  <br>

  <span class="glyphicon" 
        ng-class="isShown() ? 'glyphicon-chevron-up' : 'glyphicon-chevron-down'" 
        ng-click="hideIt()">
  </span>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the ng-show and ng-hide directive might be the best way to achieve this. That way you can have a scoped variable you can point to. You could also do an ng-class that if true, rotates the icon 180 degs. Either way it's up to you.

```
<span ng-show="$ctrl.IsToggled" type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#notes-controller"></span>
<span ng-hide="$ctrl.IsToggled" type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#notes-controller"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! how do you do the ng-class?

Comment: So ng-class takes a class name followed by an expression (true or false);

Comment: @AlvaroEnrique have a look at my answer, in case u r interested how ngClass implementation looks like.

Comment: @AlvaroEnrique Here is angular's official documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass